# How can i trigger AWS lambda for a specific input file is created in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS lambda service. I want to know if there is way to trigger a lambda function when a specific file arrives.

Comment: trigger Lambda Function once the file is uploaded to s3 bucket; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314871/how-to-trigger-my-lambda-function-once-the-file-is-uploaded-to-s3-bucket

Answer (score 2):

S3 can trigger a Lambda based on an event (example: `s3:ObjectCreated`). It cannot trigger a Lambda for a specific object. That logic should be in Lambda.

When a Lambda gets triggered due to object creation, the Lambda function also gets information about the object. Lambda can then choose to continue or exit based on the object attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, one option you could try is ["Prefix" filtering](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-s3-adds-prefix-and-suffix-filters-for-lambda-function-triggering/).

> You can also use prefix filters on the object name (the “path” is just
>   a string in reality). So if you name files like, “IMAGE001” and
>   “DOC002” and you only want to send documents to Lambda, you can set a
>   prefix of “DOC”.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 : upload those files to specific prefix and trigger an event for object created.

Option 2 : add a prefix to your object key and trigger an event for object created. Then filter event from lamda based on file name prefix